# Http 401 querying RavenDB using jquery on AppHarbor

Tags: jquery, ravendb, appharbor

I'm using RavenDB in AppHarbor to query an index using jQuery. I get an Http 401 Unauthorized. If I use my local connection string, all works fine and I suppose I need to setup RavenDB to accept my request that points to my database at Appharbor. 
The jquery I use for querying looks like this (the queryUrl is valid):

```
    function search(queryUrl) {            
        $.ajax({
            url: queryUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp',                              
            success: function (data) {
                $("#companiesHolder").empty();                    

                $.each(data.Results, function() {
                    $("#companiesHolder").append("<li><hgroup class='title'><h2>" + this.Name + "</h2><h5>" + this.Email + "</h5></hgroup></li>");
                });                                           
            },
            error: function (error, stat, message) {
                alert(stat + ":" + message);
            }
        });
```

The error i get in the browser is:

> parsererror:jQuery162024808977324209974_1337018748684 was not called

How can I configure RavenDB in AppHarbor to allow my request? Or should I send something along with the request with jQuery? (Perhaps I should send my ApiKey that is set in the documentStore?) What if for some queries I need authorization, but for others I don't, how should I handle this?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't connect from jQuery straight to your RavenDB instance. You would need to pass along your API key which then leaves it exposed in your public javascript files for anyone to connect with.

Create an API endpoint in your app and hit that, let it run the query and return the results for you.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to send along authentification, specifically the API-key [described here](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-ravendb-and-ravenhq). I'm not familiar with the scheme RavenDB uses for authentification, but you can check out the [source code](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb).

Including your API key in your public javascript files is a bad idea, though.

Comment: I used the API Key as specified, this is how I could initialize and make the first query in MVC...what I'm interested now is how could I send the API Key or something like it using jquery...